# PostgreSQL - How to extract multiple data from a column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table in postgres:

| Description | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Jane |
| Last name | Doe |
| Age | 23 |
| Country | USA |

And I want it like this:

| Name | Last_name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 23 | USA |

Please help :)

Comment: MySQL <> Postgres. Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. In normal situation, your table has more than 3 rows, and there is another column that identifies which rows belong to the same person - say `person_id`:

```
select person_id,
    max(case when description = 'Name' then value end) as name,
    max(case when description = 'Last name' then value end) as last_name,
    max(case when description = 'Age' then value end) as age,
    max(case when description = 'Country' then value end) as country
from mytable
group by person_id
```